# PHP 301 redirect location URI format

Tags: php, header, location, uri

Is this a correct URI for the `header('Location: ')`, specifically `./`?

```
header ('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header ('Location: ./');
```

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to add a trailing slash to URLs? There are better ways to do that.

Comment: I'm trying to redirect permanently from the file that contains that code to the default file (index.something) that's contained in the same folder as the initial file that did the redirection.

Comment: You should use an absolute URI. See: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must use an [absolute URI according to the spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30) so something like the following should work for you:

```
// check if the server is secure or not to determine URL prefix
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) and 'on' === $_SERVER['HTTPS']) {
    $location = 'https://';
} else {
    $location = 'http://';
}

// get the servers base URL
$location .= $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . '/';

// grab the current URI without a file name in it
$location .= dirname($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) . '/';

header('Location: ' . $location);
exit();
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use:

```
header('Location: /', false, 301);
```

I assume you want to redirect to the 'homepage', that'd be / instead of ./

Comment: Hi, I want to redirect to the root of the folder where the file that contains that code resides. In this particular case it is the root of the site as well. I'm worried because I read HTTP/1.1 requires absolute path.

Comment: According to the standard, an absolute URL is required. This will work, but is not valid

Comment: As @Pekka mentioned see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.30

Comment: I see. So is there a `real` risk by using `./` or `/`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments, didn't know an absolute url was required. Upvoted the correct solution.